# Count rows by background color failed when it count merged cells ——google sheets

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, google-sheets-formula

Hey guys I am in google sheets excel and I want to count how many rows have the merged cells based in background color.

I use the ScriptEditor to solve it. I have the next code:

```
function countColoredCells(countRange,colorRef) {
  var activeRg = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange();
  var activeSht = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var activeformula = activeRg.getFormula();
  var countRangeAddress = activeformula.match(/\((.*)\,/).pop().trim();
  var backGrounds = activeSht.getRange(countRangeAddress).getBackgrounds();
  var colorRefAddress = activeformula.match(/\,(.*)\)/).pop().trim();
  var BackGround = activeSht.getRange(colorRefAddress).getBackground();
  var countCells = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < backGrounds.length; i++)
    for (var k = 0; k < backGrounds[i].length; k++)
      if ( backGrounds[i][k] == BackGround )
        countCells = countCells + 1;
  return countCells;
};
```

it works，

but if I merge some cells, it doesn's work.

[the example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JbjPEADNBeNW4GM1Z36JBPcbvtyaBvGjQnNDBQy4DfQ/edit?usp=sharing)

What I want is to count number of rows for each block of merged cells by background color.

Comment: Can I ask you about the input and output you want for your script using your shared Spreadsheet?

Comment: =countColoredCells(H1:H10,H1)

Comment: The Input contains two parameters countRange and colorRef. the "countRange:''H1:H10 " is the range which I want to count, the colorRef:"H1" is the reference background color. The output I want is to count number of rows for each block of cells by background color. If the cells has been merged, it can also works, it can counts the numbers of the cells has been merged.

Comment: For example, in your case, when the colored cells are at "A1:A5", and "A1:A3" is merged, which do you want to retrieve 5 or 3, as the output value?

Comment: I want to retrieve 5

Comment: Thank you for replying. By the way, from ``=countColoredCells(H1:H10,H1)`` in your comment, do you want to give the values instead of range to the function?

Comment: Sorry，what's meaning of give the values instead of range to the function? I  don't understand. Could you give an example?

Comment: I apologize for my poor English skill. You want to use the function as the custom function. And you want to use it as ``=countColoredCells(H1:H10,H1)``. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Yeah, that's right. Thank you for you comments.

Comment: Thank you for replying. When the range of ``H1:H10,H1`` is used as ``=countColoredCells(H1:H10,H1)``, the values of ``H1:H10,H1`` are given to the function. So I asked whether you want to give the values instead of range to the function. In this case, the inputted range cannot be known from the function. So when you use it like ``=countColoredCells("H1:H10","H1")``, the ranges of ``H1:H10`` and ``H1`` can be given to the function. How about this?